# Dynamically create a webpage using React for many instances of the same object

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, url, dynamic

I'm new to React and web development but I was wondering if there was a way to create webpages "dynamically". For example:

I have a .json file of soccer leagues that looks like this:

```
"api": {
    "results": 1376,
    "leagues": [
        {
            "league_id": 1,
            "name": "World Cup",
        },

        {
            "league_id": 2,
            "name": "Premier League",
        },

        ....
```

I have another .js file called Leagues.js that renders all the soccer leagues from the .json along with a corresponding blue link:
The URL looks like this:

```
websiteName.me/Leagues
```

[image]

Currently each of these blue links is routed to individual .js files using react-router. Each of these .js renders a webpage corresponding to that particular league. So I have a WorldCup.js and a PremierLeague.js and these URLs following the link would be:

```
websiteName.me/Leagues/WorldCup 

websiteName.me/Leagues/PremierLeague
```

**The Question:**

Instead of having a .js file for each individual league, how could I make it "dynamic" or rather "reusable" such that I need only one LeagueInstance.js file that renders props/info passed to it.

My motivation for this is because there are 1300 leagues and I want all the pages to look the same, just displaying different information for different league objects from the .json file. Is there a way to do this or a better suggestion?

If there is a way to do this, how would I also keep the URLs the same?

Thank you lots!!!

Comment: Use a server that ignores the URL pattern and routes all traffic to one React application, then in that application fetch the data for that league and display it. In other words, you need to use React and probably `react-router-dom` too. Here is a link to the router-dom library https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic although I sense that you need to grasp some more basic react first.

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you are using react router in each of the instances, you can simply add the `leagues` route as a prefix.

So, you could create a single JS file, and on your route `path`, you would say `Leagues/WorldCup` and `Leagues/PremierLeague`.

This will require you to consolidate the code, so depending on the amount of code in each, this could be difficult.

Hopefully this helps!